# What is the use of std::execution::sequenced_policy?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am reading the book of CPP-Concurrency-In-Action-2ed-2019. In chapter 10.2.2, the author gives a simple example:

```
std::vector<int> v(1000);
int count=0;
std::for_each(std::execution::seq,v.begin(),v.end(),
  [&](int& x){ x=++count; });
```

But what is the difference with the below snippet

```
std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),
  [&](int& x){ x=++count; });
```

Is not the latter without `std::execution::seq` still store counts in sequence?
What is the use of std::execution::sequenced_policy?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation of `std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)? Yes, both calls are equal. The use case is you can pass the execution as a parameter.

Comment: You could use std::for_each in a template class of your own that also has a policy and internally uses std::for_each. So the use case is allow for "composition" (at compile time)

Comment: @f1msch I just revisited this question and realized that I don't know if I answered your questiion or not. Is there anything unanswered?

Answer (score 5):

One usage could be to supply users of your functions with the option to run them in parallel. Here's one example where the default is using the `sequenced_policy`:

```cpp
template <class ExecPolicy = std::execution::sequenced_policy>
void foo(std::vector<int>& vec, ExecPolicy pol = std::execution::seq) {
    int count = 0;
    std::for_each(pol, vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](int& x) {
        x = ++count; 
    });
}
```

Note: `++count` would have a data race if actually executed in parallel.

There's one difference though:

[`std::execution::sequenced_policy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t):

> The invocations of element access functions in parallel algorithms invoked with this policy (usually specified as `std::execution::seq`) are **indeterminately sequenced** in the calling thread.

This means that the elements could be accessed in any order.